# --Apache Rewrite Append Query String to all traffic and prevent re-direct loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Using: Apache 2.2.17

I'm trying to append a Query Parameter containing the user agent to all incoming requests, however every thing I try results in a loop.

Things I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""  
RewriteRule /(.*) /$1?Agent=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

-

```
RewriteRule /(.*) /$1?Agent=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=""
RewriteRule /.*  -  [L]
```

-

```
RewriteRule /(.*) /$1?Agent=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [R=301,QSA,E=stop:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:stop} =1
RewriteRule /.*  -  [L]
```

With the above rules I get a re-direct Loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going about it the wrong way. The below worked:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)AddAgent(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1?AddAgent=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [R=301,QSA,L]
```